# how to access table from embedded where LINQ c#

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause

Please note below is entirely made up for example sake. I have a similar query based on an sql code but couldn't translate it to LINQ to get correct value.

The sql basically looks like this:

```
select * from customers c
join proucts p on c.id = p.customerid
join credit r on r.customerid=c.id and ISNULL(r.trandate, c.registeredDate) >= c.registeredDate
```

I also tried to tweak the above sql and put the condition inside where and it also returns the same value I am getting in my #2 LINQ below(which is incorrect).

How can I use c (customer) inside .Where of credit? see code

## 1.

```
from c in customers
join p in products on c.id = p.customerid
join cr in credit.Where(r=> r.tranDate => c.registeredDate!=null?c.registeredDate : r.purchaseDate)   on c.id=cr.customerid
...
```

## 2.

I know you would suggest why not just put it in a where below like below but I am getting incorrect value.

```
from c in customers
join p in products on c.id = p.customerid
join cr in credit on c.id=cr.customerid
where r.tranDate => c.registeredDate!=null?c.registeredDate : r.purchaseDate
```

Is there a workaround? I have tried tons of others but won't get me the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ supports only equijoins. Any additional criteria should go to `where` clause. And yes, the other range variables are inaccessible from the `join` inner sequence, so the filtering should happen before or after the `join`.

So this SQL query:

```
select * from customers c
join products p on c.id = p.customerid
join credit r on r.customerid = c.id
    and ISNULL(r.trandate, c.registeredDate) >= c.registeredDate
```

directly translates to this LINQ query:

```
from c in customers
join p in products on c.id equals p.customerid
join cr in credit on c.id equals cr.customerid
where (cr.tranDate ?? c.registeredDate) >= c.registeredDate
select new { c, p, cr };
```

Optionally, the condition

```
(cr.tranDate ?? c.registeredDate) >= c.registeredDate
```

can be replaced with

```
(cr.tranDate == null || cr.tranDate >= c.registeredDate)
```